# Dropping SQL Server database: handling concurrent connections

Tags: sql-server, database, connection

During my integration tests, I try to drop database using:

```
USE master
ALTER DATABASE TestXyz SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DROP DATABASE TestXyz
```

However, quite often (given the number of tests) one of the application background processes manages to get between `SET SINGLE_USER` and `DROP DATABASE`, which makes it single user of the database and breaks the `DROP`.

I can not use `RESTRICTED_USER`, as the application currently has `db_owner` permission (due to a large amount of legacy code, some of which requires it, so it will not be changed just for the tests).

I can not use `OFFLINE` as it does not delete database files from the disk.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Are you dropping the database from script or from inside the application connected to that database? Reason Im asking is there is no reason that you can't drop an offline database.

Comment: You can drop an offline database, but the database files will be left on disk.

Comment: "manages to get between"... is that _really_ what happens. I was under the *impression* that the only connection allowed after the ALTER statement is the one that issued the ALTER statement. Unless, you execute the ALTER and DROP statements in distinct connections.

Comment: How do your integration tests would ever have any relevance if the database vanishes at random while running the tests? Seems to me the real problem is your testing framework and how you synchronize the tests. There should be no test running (no user connecting) to `TestXyz` when you're dropping it.

Comment: @Christian.K: Due to `USE master`, I am not really connected to test database. I can not `USE TestXyz` as it will not let me drop it if I am connected to it.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: The database is being reset between the tests, so in the middle of the test nothing bad happens. However the system is not shut down between the tests, as it is really slow to restart and is mostly stateless anyway (aside from the DB). Failing background tasks between tests are fine as they are mostly about DB-related maintenance, which is not needed in tests (and I can not switch these tasks off easily just for tests, as they are in legacy code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it using the following approach:

```
ALTER LOGIN MyAppUser DISABLE
ALTER DATABASE TestXyz SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DROP DATABASE TestXyz
ALTER LOGIN MyAppUser ENABLE
```

Since I can use different login for test database management process, this allows me to block application from accessing the DB. (The reason for `SINGLE_USER` here is just to kick already connected users. I haven't checked if `ALTER LOGIN` already does that, but I assume it does not).

Alternative option is to delete `MyAppUser` from the database before dropping it, however I thought about it only now and do not have code for it.

Answer (score 1):

OK plan b... iterate a drop of connections and rename the DB to get it away from the applications domain. Then drop it. To handle iterating through connections a try catch on the rename will hopefully allow it to run until it is able to drop the connection. Example code below creates a DB TestDB; renames it to testdb2 in the while loop before dropping it after the loop has succeeded.

```
-- Setup a scratch Db for testing
create database testdb
go
use testdb

while exists (select name from sys.databases where name = 'testdb')
Begin
  DECLARE @DbName nvarchar(50) SET @DbName = N'testdb'

    DECLARE @EXECSQL varchar(max) SET @EXECSQL = ''

    SELECT @EXECSQL = @EXECSQL + 'Kill ' + Convert(varchar, SPId) + ';' 
    FROM MASTER..SysProcesses 
    WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@DbName) AND SPId <> @@SPId

    EXEC(@EXECSQL)

    Begin try
        EXEC sp_renamedb 'testdb', 'testdb2'
    end try
    Begin Catch
    print 'failed to rename'
    End Catch
end

drop database testdb2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

1. Stop application services and run your query.
2. Stop application services and restart `SQL Server Services` and then run your query.